# How to use shared project which is in Bit-bucket?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, dockerfile

i have three repositories in bit-bucket( all three are .net-core)
1.web
2.core
3.wed.admin

all three have common project which is in another repository(common infrastructure)
so how can i import that common project in Docker file to compile the code.

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason they're not all in the same repo? Repos are meant to be self-contained. Consider using a subtree or submodule to "include" other repos inside another repo (subtrees are now preferred over submodules).

Comment: You can create a nuget package for shared project

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski While you *can* deploy NuGet using Docker, that doesn't help the OP's problem of consolidating source-code located in 3 different git repos.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski its not a nuget package its a shared project